# Ocean current speed use velocity components (u,v,w)

Tags: vectors

Properties of problem: friction-less @all locations, non rotating planet

So I am told that a steady current has the velocity components $(u,v,w)$ and $u$ mainly depends on x.

Also this was stated in the problem and I have no idea what it means $O(u) >> O(v,w)$. What is $O$?

$x1 = 0m$, 
$x2=50,000m$

$Depth=500m$

I'm told that the depth drops by $.9m$ and that $u1=0.3 m/s$ at $x1$

I need to find $u2$ at $x2$, however since the problem states that $u$ **mainly** depends on x do I need to include $y$ into calculating $u$, and if so what equations should I focus on?

If I don't need to include $y$ in calculating $u$ then wouldn't $u1 = u2$, but that seems too easy.

Comment: $O(\cdot)$ stands for "order of". $O(u) \gg  O(v,w)$ means $u$ is significantly larger than $v, w$. i.e the velocity vector is pointing very close to the $x$-direction. You don't need $y$, what you need is the "volume" (not the velocity) of water flowing towards the $x$-direction per second is a constant.

Comment: @achillehui How would volume affect $u$ at $x2$?

Comment: Since $|v| \ll |u|$, to first approximation, we can assume the span in y direction is fixed, say it is $Y$. At $x = x_1$, the depth $D_1 = 500$ and $x = x_2$, the depth is $D_2 = 500.9$. The volume of water enter at $x = x_1$ per second is $u_1 D_1 Y$, the volume of water leave at $x = x_2$ per second is $u_2 D_2 Y$. If we can
ignore the possibility that water evaporate away, the volume enter needs to equal to volume leave (since we are in steady state). This means $u_1 D_1 Y = u_2 D_2 Y \implies u_1 D_1 = u_2 D_2$

Comment: @achillehui ahhhhhhhhhhhh, I see now!  Thank you so much

Comment: @achillehui so $u2 = 2.99m/s$ A very small reduction in speed.

Comment: Since the depth changes by $0.2%$, $u_2$ should change for about $0.2%$ too. If $u_1 = 0.3m/s$ then $u_2$ should be around $0.2995 m/s$ (BTW, I'm not 100% sure whether the term "the depth drops by 0.9m" means the depth increases or decreases or not. if it means the depth decreases to 499.1m, then $u_2$ will be $0.3005 m/s$ instead).